# Only reading a single character with readPassword()

Tags: java, console, passwords

When I run my program with:

```
        String line;
        if (null != System.console())
        {
            char [] c = System.console().readPassword("prompt>");
            line = (null != c) ? new String(c) : "";
        }
```

I get the prompt, and if my password were "abcd", as soon as I type the "a" (without pressing Enter, or anything else) the `readPassword()` is returning with just the single letter "a" in the `c` array, and not waiting for me to type "bcd".  What am I doing wrong, or am I supposed to call `readPassword()` in a loop?  (The examples I've seen don't seem to do that).  That is, I am expecting (and want) `readPassword()` to read a line until the user presses Enter, but it is returning after a single character is typed.

Thanks.

Comment: You depart significantly from the [Javadoc example](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Console.html) I suggest you don't ;)

Comment: I ran your code, and it lets me type in an entire password.

Comment: If you're running it from an IDE console, some get IO, particularly I, wrong